# Check if a process is running on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, top

I am running a python programme on a remote machine using ssh.

It includes a timer, so the main body of the code won't do anything until a certain time of the day.

I want to check that the code is still running - I tried to do `top` and initially (first few seconds) it showed me that a python process was running. But then it disappeared - I assume because the code isn't really doing any work - it is just "waiting". But the code is still technically running.

Is there any other way I can check it if it still running when I ssh into the remote machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ps`, code below will show process which contains name passed to `grep`.

`ps aux | grep "[^]]hello_world"`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is your python process could start an  TCP echo service, that is pretty easy, do nothing but echo what your client input is. In this way you even do not need the ssh, you can just telnet or nc the ip and port of your echo service, if your process is running, it will answer. But one more thing, configure your remote machine firewall to allow access of your echo service.

Comment: Oh yeah, provide it by also proving it all.

Comment: this approach might have flaws. When looking "for" something, if you dont find some circumstantial proves it is there  - it might be wrong to assume that it is not there. If you want your python to answer socket connections - you will need to make a thread (or a process?) for the socket server-side in the python. If that thread is stuck - it will not answer the socket and the other side might think the python is not there while, in fact, it is. IMHO, the only bulletproof way to know if the process is there is by checking ps instead of asking the process if it is there ..

Comment: @LouisShraga Yes, I know what you mean. But how could you suppose the thread will be stuck? Why you sure your remote terminal process will not be suck? If that could happen, how could you do your “ps” command, I wonder. And how could you use “ping” to make sure one remote host is working? Why you never wonder the “ping” response process could not be stuck? Could you tell me why? If you don’t trust anything, you could not do anything. There is a risk of something to happen, does not mean it must be. There is even a risk of your system crashing, but it does not mean you could not use it! Right?

Comment: @Neal.Marlin - you are right, in general. It depends on your needs. If you build a nuclear plant SW, you'd better follow all that chain of instances that you've mentioned and 'understand' where the fault is. For OP - he wanted `to check that the code is still running`. He did not want to asses the health of the system. And so I wanted to emphasize that you should consider well if it is ok for your situation to check if the `code is running` by ... asking the code itself `are you running` ? That is why i said that there `might` be flaws :)

Comment: @LouisShraga All right. One thing I must mention, is you could not know anything from the thing itself, but from its impact. There is lot of examples that we judge things exist from its impact, because an invisible drag is the same to a drag that never existed.  We ping the remote host to test if it’s alive. We ssh -Tv to see safe connection process.  Even the ps could not tell the process is working properly. It maybe suspended for a while and couldn’t do anything, bu the process is still alive.